# How are ties broken for MVP in Rocket League?

Tags: rocket-league

I just finished a game of doubles where my partner and I each finished on 480 points in a win. We each had one goal, two saves, and three shots. I got a first touch with 2 seconds left, and at the end of the game, I got the MVP and he didn't. How is the MVP decided in cases of level points (and pretty much everything else being equal)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is from the [Rocket League Wiki](http://rocketleague.wikia.com/wiki/Points)

> Each player can gain points from various actions throughout the match. At the end of the match, the player on the winning team with the most points gets MVP (most valuable player) and is awarded an additional 100 points. If two players on the winning team have the same number of points when the match ends, MVP is awarded to the first of the tying players in alphabetical order based on the player names.

Which seems kind of strange to me, I'd previously assumed it would go:

Points -> Goals -> Saves -> Assists

Comment: Me too, but I guess that's the final word! Thanks for the information.

Comment: @Rome_Leader yeah, I would have thought there'd be a priority order for how points were scored in the event of tie, although in your specific situation with everything being equal I don’t know how it could have separated them, possibly it could be done by somehow counting extra for Epic Saves/Long Goals/Aerial Goals in a tie?

Comment: That's certainly how it works in most sports, such as going first to goal difference and then goals for/goals against in a league table. I have no idea if we also had an equal number of centers or first touches or whatever, but your suggestion does seem most logical to me as the next most valuable metrics.